# What is the easiest way to upgrade an EC2 instance type?

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

In order to upgrade our EC2 instances (or downgrade for that matter) I use the AWS console to "Create Image (EBS AMI)" and then I launch the AMI once it has been created.  Is there a way that would make it possible for me to upgrade/downgrade without having to create the AMI?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the API tools command ec2-modify-instance-attribute. You need to stop the instance, apply the command and start it again.

I've done this with my Linux AMI's. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to persist changes is via EBS.  AMIs are read-only, though you can always use one AMI to create another.